# Нужно получить значение во вторых кавычках (цвет)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Из строки вида:

```
{\"color\":\"#0038ff\"}
```

Нужно получить значение цвета из второй пары кавычек (цвет).

Я только изучаю пхп, и пока не знаю как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

В данной ситуации можно обойтись без регулярных выражений.

```php
$string = '{\"color\":\"#0038ff\"}';
// Уберём экранирование кавычек, чтобы получить корректный JSON
$json = str_replace('\"', '"', $string);

$result = json_decode($json);
echo $result->color; // Выведет строку #0038ff
```